# PCI root port send abnormal CPLD to endpoint

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, dma, pci

Working on a PCI express fpga PIO and its linux soft driver.
My fpga acts as an Endpoint and the PC is the Root Port. The FPGA firmware supports 32 bits DMA.

When my fpga send a READ REQUEST to PC, the PC send back an abnormal CPLD.
The TLP is captured with the FPGA's on chip logic analyzer.
Here is the detail of how the pb is found:
On the side of 'user program', my user program requests a memory zone with `malloc` and writes some dwords(>32 DWords) into it. Then it calls `write` to write those DWs to the device's file handle.
On the side of 'kernel module', my fpga is registered as a 'char device' and its .write system call is defined like:

```
static ssize_t fops_write(struct file *file, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *startOffset)
{   
    ...
    copy_from_user(dma_addr, buf, count);
    dma_write(dma_addr, count);
    ...
    return 0; 
}
```

And in the `dma_write` function, I process the DMA:

```
int dma_write(char *dma_addr, u32 count)
{
    dma_map_single(...dma_addr...);
    dma_set_descriptor(...);
    wait_event(...);
    dma_unmap_single(...dma_addr...);
    return 0;
}
```

The `dma_set_descriptor` will write to BAR0 to configure some registers in the device so that the device will then send a read request to get data from PC. Once the data transfer is done, my device will send a interrupt, and the driver's irq handler will wake up the `wait_event(...);`.
The `dma_addr` is obtained from `dma_alloc_coherent` like this:
`dma_addr = dma_alloc_coherent(dev, 4096*1024, dma_addr_hw, GFP_KERNEL);`

When the read request is sent, and the PC begins to send a CPLD in respond to this request, the problem happens:
It seems that the PC can send only the first 32 Dwords(128 bytes) of all the DWords got from user space. Begin from the 33th dword, it just repeat the first 32 until it reaches the request's length.
For example:
There are 36 Dwords to be send to fpga and defined like 0,10,20,30,...,310,320,330,340,350. But what my fpga receives is like: 0,10,20,30,...,310,0,10,20,30.

These datas are verified with the on chip logic analyzer, so I think the problem comes from the driver or the PC but not from the fpga.
The `pci_set_dma_mask(pci_device, DMA_BIT_MASK(32))` returns 0, so it seems not a dma mask issus.
Two days working on this pb but still no clue..

It's a little complicated to describe my question, I hope you can understand the things above and help me with this.
If there is any further information that you need, just tell me.

Comment: I'm no expert on low-level PCI workings, but I would wonder how your endpoint is composing the Read-Request TLP. Is it a single request? What's in it? And what's in the Completion TLP? (To me, it seems unlikely to be a problem in the root complex request handling.)

Comment: Also, are you sure that you actually have the correct values in the buffer at `dma_addr`?